# Ts-Loader Won't Allow Dynamic Module Imports

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, ts-loader

I am trying to compile a simple `index.ts` file using webpack's `ts-loader`; the file uses dynamic imports. In my `webpack.config.js` I have my alias set to: `` Images: `path.resolve(__dirname, './src/images') ``, and my `tsconfig.json`  has `"baseUrl": "./src", "paths": { "Images/*": ["images/*"]}` . Both of these should work fine in resolving the import path for this function:

```
function sampleComponent() {
  return import('Images/cow.jpg')
    .then(({ default: cowImg }) => {
      const img = new Image(400, 400);
      img.src = cowImg;
      img.classList.add('test-style');
      return img; 
    })  
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the error: `Cannot find module Images/cow.jpg or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)` .